# Как окрасить 70% stroke в #f3ca80, а 30% в #403f4e у circle. svg

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-path

**К примеру у меня есть вот такая окружность**

```html
<div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center"> 
  <svg width="500" height="500"> 
    <circle r="180" cx="232" cy="232" stroke-dasharray="2 3" stroke="#f3ca80" fill="none" stroke-width="30"></circle> 
  </svg> 
</div>
```

Сейчас все `100%` окрашены в цвет `#f3ca80`

Я смог сделать вариант только с `50%` процентами, вот он:

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center"> 
  <svg width="500" height="500"> 
    <defs> 
      <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="464" height="464" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
        <circle r="180" cx="232" cy="232" stroke-dasharray="2 3" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="40"></circle> 
      </mask> 
    </defs> 
    <g mask="url(#mask)"> 
      <circle cx="232" cy="232" r="180" opacity="1" fill="#403f4e"></circle> 
      <path class="upgrade__circle-path" d="M0 180 A 100 100 1 0 0 0 -180 z" fill="#f3ca80"></path> 
    </g> 
  </svg> 
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Цель:**

Cоотношение должно меняться динамически и зависеть от одного (макс. двух) параметра(ов), параметр должно быть в % или чтобы его можно было в них перевести.

**К примеру:**

1. `x = 26%` значить соотношение будет `26%` `#f3ca80` и `64%` `#403f4e`
2. `x = 42%`, `y = 58%` значить соотношение будет `42%` `#f3ca80` и `58%` `#403f4e`

Для решение данной задачи можете использовать php, svg, html, css, js, ajax, jquery

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QWVwyrN - ради бога - теперя можете использовать php,  js, ajax, jquery

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ExeaEBg - вот так это работает с input

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLxyjge - вот так выводят проценты